# What is the proper REST URI for a JPA entity with a composite primary key in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, http, netbeans, jax-rs

I have the following setting.

Technologies used:

- NetBeans IDE
- MySQL DB
- EclipseLink JPA
- JAX-RS

I generated my entities and rest services using the NetBeans tool "RESTful Web Services from Database. Now I have a view in my DB where a row is uniquely identified by a compount consisting of two columns (I know it makes no sense to speak of a primary key regarding views, but let's call it primary key anyway, for simplicity). I modeled the view as an entity with an embedded composite primary key as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserAmountView")
@XmlRootElement
public class UserAmountView implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
  protected UserAmountPK userAmountPK;

  // fields, constructors, getters, setters etc.

}

@Embeddable
public class UserAmountPK implements Serializable {

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "UserID")
  private int userID;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "BalanceID")
  private Integer balanceID;

  public UserAmountPK() {
  }

  public UserAmountPK(int userID, Integer balanceID) {
    this.userID = userID;
    this.balanceID = balanceID;
  }

  // getters and setters etc...
}
```

Now my question is, how to I best RESTfully address an instance of such an entity? NetBeans generates a procedure using matrix parameters (one for each part/column of the composite key) for normal tables with composite primary keys, so I took this approach over for my view. I would expect, that I can GET the entity consisting of primary key (7, 3) under **.../wgm.rest.useramountview;userID=7;balanceID=3**, but of course this doesn't work since the matrix parameters are in the same path segement as wgm.rest.useramountview, so the request will just return all existing entities. Next I tried **.../wgm.rest.useramountview/;userID=7;balanceID=3** which gives me the same result (why?). Only if I insert something in between the '/' and ';', then it works as expected and returns the entity identified by (7, 3), e.g. **.../wgm.rest.useramountview/foo;userID=7;balanceID=3**.
Obviously, I would like to avoid always having to insert a 'foo' in the URL. What are the alternatives?

My service class currently looks as follows:

```
@Stateless
@Path("wgm.rest.useramountview")
public class UserAmountViewFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<UserAmountView> {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WGManagerPU")
  private EntityManager em;

  private UserAmountPK getPrimaryKey(PathSegment pathSegment) {
    wgm.rest.UserAmountPK key = new wgm.rest.UserAmountPK();
    javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = pathSegment.getMatrixParameters();
    java.util.List<String> userID = map.get("userID");
    if (userID != null && !userID.isEmpty()) {
      key.setUserID(new java.lang.Integer(userID.get(0)));
    }
    java.util.List<String> balanceID = map.get("balanceID");
    if (balanceID != null && !balanceID.isEmpty()) {
      key.setBalanceID(new java.lang.Integer(balanceID.get(0)));
    }
    return key;
  }

  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public UserAmountView find(@PathParam("id") PathSegment id) {
    wgm.rest.UserAmountPK key = getPrimaryKey(id);
    return super.find(key);
  }

  @GET
  @Override
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public List<UserAmountView> findAll() {
     return super.findAll();
  }

  // ...
}
```

## Update:

Another possibility would be to include the single columns of the composite key as path params, like this:

```
  @GET
  @Path("{userID}/{balanceID}")
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public UserAmountView find(
      @PathParam("userID") String userID,
      @PathParam("balanceID") String balanceID) {

    wgm.rest.UserAmountPK key = 
        new UserAmountPK(new Integer(userID), new Integer(balanceID));
    return super.find(key);
  }
```

But still, this does not satisfy me because that would look like a subresource. In fact, both of the path parameters are on the same hierarchical level for identifying **one** resource.

## Solution:

I finally came up with an adapted version of Roman Vottner's answer (see below): Using matrix parameters directly on the base resource path and differentiating between the two cases directly inside the method. I had to wrap the result in a Response object as the return types do not match (`UserAmountView` for `find` vs. `List<UserAmountView>` for `findAll`). The result looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("wgm.rest.useramountview")
public class UserAmountViewFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<UserAmountView> {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WGManagerPU")
  private EntityManager em;
  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Response findAll(
      @MatrixParam("userID") String userID,
      @MatrixParam("balanceID") String balanceID) {
     if (userID != null && balanceID != null) {
       wgm.rest.UserAmountPK key = new UserAmountPK(Parser.asIntOrNull(userID), Parser.asIntOrNull(
      balanceID));
       return Response.ok(super.find(key)).build();
    } else {
      return Response.ok(super.findAll()).build();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass your compound key as matrix parameter `.../wgm.rest.useramountview;userID=7;balanceID=3` but you have a defined path structures as either `.../wgm.rest.useramountview` or `.../wgm.rest.useramountview/{id}` where `id` is also defined as path parameter.

As matrix parameters belong to the resource they are defined on, JAX-RS will invoke the closest possible resource which is the `findAll` method on using a URI like `.../wgm.rest.useramountview;userID=7;balanceID=3` though here you do not extract the matrix parameters. This is the reason why all entries are returned instead of the one specific on invoking that URI.

The second call `.../wgm.rest.useramountview/foo;userID=7;balanceID=3` succeeds as you now provide the ID `foo;userID=7;balanceID=3` to the service which JAX-RS will now resolve to the `find(...)` method. As you use a PathSegment object here, you simply ignore the actual `ID` value but just collect the matrix parameter defined on it.

To deal with matrix parameters without having to use some additional currently unused ID path parameter you should refactor the `find` and `findAll` methods to something like:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public UserAmountView find(@MatrixParam("userID") Integer userID,
                           @MatrixParam("balanceID") Integer balanceID) {
    if (null != userID && null != balanceID) {
        return findOne(userID, balanceID);
    } else {
        return findAll();
    }
}
```

As with `PathParam` or `QueryParam` you can also directly inject the `MatrixParam` as depicted in the example above. You can also re-use the `PathSegment` on the `findAll` method directly and retrieve the matrix parameters as you do, but I guess that using the `@MatrixParam` annotation is a bit more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks Roman! I finally came up with an adapted version of your solution. The problem is, the return type of `findAll` is a `List<UserAmountView>` while the return type of `find` is `UserAmountView`, so I aditionally had to wrap the result in a Response using the `Response.ok()` builder. I think, this is the cleanest solution. I somehow wanted to stick to the scheme that we have one method for each resource / resource type, but I think it is fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a side effect of *MatrixParam,PathSegment* values, first tag is actually a normal path parameter followed by *;key1=val1;key2=val2* values.

Have you considered to use a normal *&key1=val1&key2=val2* query parameters?

Comment: I don't see how this is helping. I think with query parameters, there is the exact same issue. If I want to use _somepath_/wgm.rest.useramountview?userID=7&balanceID=3, this is interfering with the findAll, i.e. an IllegalStateException is thrown because of ambiguous resource method for GET and the same MIME types. Of course, I could again do something like _somepath_/wgm.rest.useramountview/foo?userID=7&balanceID=3 - and this is what I would like to avoid.